# Why is there a difference between the following lines of code? (Recursion based question)

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

Here's the first part:

```
bool coinChangeFn(vector<int>& coins, int amount, int level, int& result) { 
    if (amount < 0) {
        cout << "Amount is less than 0!" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (amount == 0) {
        cout << "Amount is 0. Level is " << level << endl;
        result = min(result, level);
        return true;
    }

    bool flag = false;
    for (auto coin : coins) {
        cout << "Amount: " << amount
             << " Level: " << level
             << " Coin: "  << coin 
             << endl;
        bool temp = coinChangeFn(coins, amount - coin, level + 1, result); // THIS LINE
        flag = flag || temp; // THIS LINE
    }
    return flag;
}

int coinChange(vector<int>& coins, int amount) {
    int result{INT_MAX};
    return coinChangeFn(coins, amount, 0, result) ? result : -1;
}
```

And here's the second version of the code

```
bool coinChangeFn(vector<int>& coins, int amount, int level, int& result) {
    if (amount < 0) {
        cout << "Amount is less than 0!" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (amount == 0) {
        cout << "Amount is 0. Level is " << level << endl;
        result = min(result, level);
        return true;
    }

    bool flag = false;
    for (auto coin : coins) {
        cout << "Amount: " << amount
             << " Level: " << level
             << " Coin: "  << coin
             << endl;
        flag = flag || coinChangeFn(coins, amount - coin, level + 1, result); // THIS LINE
    }
    return flag;
}

int coinChange(vector<int>& coins, int amount) {
    int result{INT_MAX};
    return coinChangeFn(coins, amount, 0, result) ? result : -1;
}
```

I've marked the code under question as "THIS LINE" in the comments. I expected them to have the same behavior, however the first version stopped the recursion earlier than expected.

Comment: If flag is true, coinChangeFn() doesn't get called. || is "short circuit evaluation". Don't evaluate the 2nd operand if it isn't needed to determine the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re seeing the effect of short-circuit evaluation. In C++, since `true || anything` is `true`, if the first operand to `||` is true, then the second argument isn’t evaluated.

Therefore, if you write

```
flag = flag || /* recursive call */;
```

and `flag` is already true, then no call will be made.

On the other hand, the bitwise OR operator `|` doesn’t short-circuit. Therefore, if you write

```
flag |= /* recursive call */;
```

then the call will always be made.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, the `||` operator short-circuits. If the first operand is true, the second will not be evaluated. If you wish to make sure it *is* evaluated, you have to evaluate it and *then* use the returned value.

```cpp
int result = coinChangeFn(coins, amount - coin, level + 1, result);
flag = flag || result;
```